# Выйдя к воде, начало улучшаться

Tags: стилистика

При чтении книг, часто встречаю подобное написание, и оно цепляет неправильностью:

«Выйдя к воде, угрюмое и злое настроение понемногу начало улучшаться».

То есть, по смыслу получается, что это не герои вышли к воде, а настроение? Нужно добавлять: «Выйдя к воде, путники ощутили, что…»
Правильно? Или я не права?

Спасибо.

Comment: Лучше добавить, чтобы не было каламбура, а еще лучше вообще убрать настроение с сделать описание, того как оно улучшилось. Выйдя к воде, они ощутили свежий, немного влажный ветерок; прозрачная поверхность озера отражала небо и плывущие облака, приходилось жмурится от играющего в бликами солнца - и тп... А дальше: Виталик приободрившись - сказал, сделал.. Не нужно писать, что "настроение улучшилось", нужно описывать как оно улучшилось, от чего. Это будет вызывать у читать желание проживать жизнью героев, рядом с ними. А путники - это они, настроение - их, уровень отстранения от героев- сильный.

Comment: А почему запятая после _книг_?